# cannot drop jar from Oracle database with dropjava command

Tags: java, oracle

I am trying to execute dropjava command to drop a jar file in the database....

```
dropjava -u username/password@schema -v -r abc.jar
```

... but it is giving me the following error:

```
ORA-29537: class or resource cannot be created or dropped directly
```

What is the problem?

I loaded the JAR using this command:

```
loadjava -u username/password@schema -v -r -f abc.jar
```

Comment: What was the *precise* command (including options) you used to load the jar into the database?  What is the precise set of options you're using with `dropjava`?

Comment: The exact command is: dropjava -u username/password@schema -v -r abc.jar

Comment: Yes but did you use any other options when you loaded teh jar?

Comment: to load the jar i've used the following command: loadjava -u username/password@schema -v -r -f abc.jar

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR: An java source object (`object_type='JAVA SOURCE'`) which defines the same class already exists in the database. Drop it first.

---

```
$ oerr ora 29537
```

> 29537, 00000, "class or resource cannot be created or dropped directly"
>   // *Cause: An attempt was made to create or drop **a Java class** or resource that
>   //          **is known to result from compilation of an existing Java source object.**
>   // *Action: Act on the class or resource by acting on the source, or change
>   //          the source so that it no longer defines the class or resource.

Consider the following MCVE:

```
$ echo "public class SomeClass { }" >SomeClass.java
$ javac SomeClass.java
$ jar -cvf SomeClass.jar SomeClass.class
$ conndb="user/pass@db_server/sevice_name"

$ loadjava -u $conndb -r -v SomeClass.jar
resolving: class SomeClass
Classes Loaded: 1

$ dropjava -u $conndb -v SomeClass.jar
dropping: class SomeClass
```

So far, so good. Now, let's create the java source object that defines the same class:

```
$ sqlplus -l -s $conndb <<+++
create or replace and compile java source named "SomeClass" as
$(<SomeClass.java)
/
+++
Java created.
```

Then the class can be neither created nor dropped directly:

```
$ loadjava -u $conndb -r -v SomeClass.jar
Error while creating class SomeClass
    ORA-29537: class or resource cannot be created or dropped directly

$ dropjava -u $conndb -v SomeClass.jar
Error while dropping SomeClass
    ORA-29537: class or resource cannot be created or dropped directly
```

Drop the existing java source that defines class with the same name and it'll work again:

```
$ sqlplus -l -s $conndb <<+++
drop java source SomeClass;
+++
Java dropped.

$ loadjava -u $conndb -r -v SomeClass.jar
resolving: class SomeClass
Classes Loaded: 1

$ dropjava -u $conndb -v SomeClass.jar
dropping: class SomeClass
```

Answer (score 2):

Example of dropping java resources created after certain date:

```
declare
  cursor c is 
   SELECT dbms_java.longname (t.object_name) long_n
   FROM 
    user_objects
   WHERE 
   (object_name NOT LIKE 'SYS_%' AND 
    object_name NOT LIKE 'CREATE$%' AND 
    object_name NOT LIKE 'JAVA$%' AND 
    object_name NOT LIKE 'LOADLOB%') AND
    object_type LIKE 'JAVA %' AND
    created > to_date('20190830', 'YYYYMMDD');

begin
  for i in c loop
    dbms_java.dropjava(i.long_n);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a guess but I think it is worth a shot.

Connect to your database as the appropriate user and trying dropping the JAR with [the PL/SQL package DBMS_JAVA](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14187/appendixa.htm).  In SQL*Plus that would look likeL

```
dbms_java.dropjava('-jarsasdbobjects abc.jar');
```

The PL/SQL takes the same options as the `dropjava` commandline.

Comment: not working for me , getting not found , i mean not found the jar i am trying to drop which was loaded by loadjava

Answer (score 0):

This command works, I think:

```
dropjava -u username/password@schema -v -r -f abc.jar
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select 'exec dbms_java.dropjava('''||dbms_java.longname (object_name)||''');' from user_objects where object_type like '%JAVA%';
```

Comment: and run as script

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. From [Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/27273511).